# Expresso Store: Shipping Confirmation email template - tracking number

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any way to pass to shipping confirmation email template a tracking number from the order? I have try to use order custom field but it comes as not editable at the store back end so when order is shipped then tracking number can be pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `{order_status_message}` in that case as other fields cannot be edited.